# How to keep webpack from bundling a package?

Tags: webpack, sequelize.js

I'm using Postgres and Sequelize in my webpack project. I'm running into an list of errors, where it appears that webpack is trying to bundle sequelize or the postgres (pg) package:

```
ERROR in ./~/pg/lib/connection.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /Users/dace/Code/personal/my_project/node_modules/pg/lib
 @ ./~/pg/lib/connection.js 1:10-24

ERROR in ./~/pg/lib/connection.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in /Users/dace/Code/personal/my_project/node_modules/pg/lib
 @ ./~/pg/lib/connection.js 78:14-28

ERROR in ./~/pg/lib/native/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'pg-native' in /Users/dace/Code/personal/my_project/node_modules/pg/lib/native
 @ ./~/pg/lib/native/index.js 1:13-33

ERROR in ./~/pg/lib/connection-parameters.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'dns' in /Users/dace/Code/personal/my_project/node_modules/pg/lib
 @ ./~/pg/lib/connection-parameters.js 2:10-24

ERROR in ./~/pgpass/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/dace/Code/personal/my_project/node_modules/pgpass/lib
 @ ./~/pgpass/lib/index.js 4:9-22
```

In my webpack's dev.config.js file I have:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'index.js'),
  output: {
    publicPath: '/build/',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: ['babel'],
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

then in my index.js I have:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var connection = new Sequelize('dev', 'dace', 'root', {
  dialect: 'postgres',
});

var Article = connection.define('article', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
})

connection.sync().then(function() {
  Article.create({
    name: 'Dace'
  });
});
```

I'm guessing that I need to keep webpack from trying to bundle sequelize or pg as it works when I remove webpack from the project altogether. Is there a way where I can configure webpack to ignore bundling these packages throughout my app?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect to happen on the client side when `index.js` loads?

Comment: I'll eventually query and then display the data with React, but for now Just trying to get it to connect and insert this one entry.

Comment: Do you want to run `index.js` on the server side also or only on the client?

Comment: Yes, both on the server and client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use anything that deals with database, filesystem, etc from the client code. For example `fs` module (i.e. `filesystem`) is something that is  defined only in `node` environment, the browser does not have any clue, what `fs` might be. The same is true for `net` (which is implemented differently or not implemented at all in the browser). No wonder, that `webpack` got all confused about it :)

My suggestion: Rewrite your code to client, server and common parts; ensure, that client and server parts are doing only things that make sense in node / browser environment.

Comment: Thanks Tomas. This is starting to make more sense. On the client side, user will eventually be able to get/post/put/delete - so all of this should be handled within my server.js (file with my express config), correct?

Comment: Cool. Could you please then accept the answer? Also, ESTE is a nice and definitely woth looking at starter kit for nodejs isomorphic apps,  you can also notice the diferentiation to server, client, common and react native code: https://github.com/este/este